# which one is the correct statement of "Law of definite proportion"?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, physical-organic-chemistry

according to my genius Teacher ' this law state that "the composition of a compound in terms of atoms (**Not Mass**) remains constant".
His **Proof**:
H2O and D2O are similar compounds (because H and D have same atomic number)...Now the story start from here--->
The ratio by mass for H2O= 1:8, and for D2O= 1:4 (both have different ratios, although they are similar compounds- so This law shound not be defined on the basis of mass)
Now, Ratio by atom for H2O= 2:1 and for D2O= 2:1 (both give same results, so this law should be defined on the basis of No.of atoms)...**End of Proof**
Is the problem lie in similar compounds or my teacher is correct and the world is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Law of Definite Proportions was defined before we knew about isotopes. Sure, you can give a modern version of it, but that's not the original version.

If you have no notion of isotopes, then the mass is just a constant multiple (specifically, the atomic mass) of the number of atoms, in which case, the two definitions become equivalent.